# SP2013 - Saved Searches

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, search, save

Is there a way out-of-the-box or with some customisation or custom code to allow users to save their 'favourite' search queries and be able to use them on demand?  Ideally we would like for them to be saved and retrievable within their My Site or directly from the search page as a drop-down or something similar.

Comment: They could always create a browser bookmark. 

I created a solution for a client that applyies JS to every page in a sitecollection (Custom Action) and in that code there is a "Favorite" and option added. We write the information via jsom in the users profile and retrieve it on page load.

Answer (score 1):

Their is no OOTB method to save the searches, rather you have to create your own custom code.here are couple of ideas.

[Create a ‘Save My Searches’ Feature in SharePoint 2010 with JavaScript/jQuery](http://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/2013/08/14/create-a-save-my-searches-feature-in-sharepoint-2010-with-javascript-jquery-aspx/)

[Get last search query](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/47912/get-last-search-query)